# PyOpenCL 2020.1 - Device side queue is unimplemented

Tags: python-3.x, debian, opencl, amd-processor, pyopencl

I am facing an issue with `pyopencl` I never had before (see piece of code below)

the issue : `Device side queue is unimplemented (clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties.c:93)`

Have any of you faced this problem before?
Do you have any idea where it comes from?

```bash
user@debian_9.5:~# pip3 freeze | grep pyopencl
   pyopencl==2020.1


user@debian_9.5:~# python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

   >>> import pyopencl as cl
   >>> ctx = cl.create_some_context()

   Choose platform:
   [0] <pyopencl.Platform 'Portable Computing Language' at 0x7fb1fbfba020>
   Choice [0]:0
   Set the environment variable PYOPENCL_CTX='0' to avoid being asked again.

   >>> print(ctx)
   <pyopencl.Context at 0x55c1e9a87440 on <pyopencl.Device 'pthread-AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1950X 16-Core Processor' on 'Portable Computing Language' at 0x55c1ea017430>>

   >>> queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
   Device side queue is unimplemented (clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties.c:93)
```

My setup is as folows:

- AMD-Ryzen 1950X
- Debian 9.5
- Python 3.5.3

Answer (score 0):

Solved by doing

```
user@debian_9.5:~$  pip uninstall pyopencl && apt install python3-pyopencl
```